# How to get at my json value using await instead of just .then

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, async.js

This works

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log('4. userId = ' + json.userId))
```

to give me:

```
4. userId = 1
```

But when I try to use await

```
{
  async function doFetch() {
    const result = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    console.log('8. await: ' + String(result.json()));
  } doFetch();
}
```

I get the promise instead as output

```
8. await: [object Promise]
```

How to get at the JSON value?

### Update

Thanks for answers:

```
console.log('8. await: ' + String(await result.json()));
```

I should have been clearer though, how to get the userId?  I tried

```
console.log('8. await: ' + String(await result.json().userId));
```

but I get undefined

Comment: fixed typo of user=1 hardcoded to be userid (what the code actually has)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you need two `then` calls in the first version, then expect to need two `await`s in the second version. The `json()` method returns a promise.

So change:

```
console.log('8. await: ' + String(result.json()));
```

To:

```
console.log('8. await: ' + String(await result.json()));
```

To get a property, just do as usual, but make sure you have awaited the object first. So first close the parentheses:

```js
(async function () {
    const result = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    console.log('8. await: ' + (await result.json()).userId);
})();
```

If you need more than just that one property, then just first get the whole object in a variable, and use that variable from then on:

```js
(async function () {
    const result = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    const obj = await result.json();
    console.log('userId = ' + obj.userId);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks - how to get the actual userId ?

Comment: See addition to answer. If you need access to more properties, then better put the awaited result in an variable, and continue to work with that...

Comment: Thanks again trincot. however I'm getting undefined with `console.log('8. await: ' + String(await result.json()).userId);` and i tried `.blob` too

Comment: Try outputting `JSON.stringify(await result.json(), null, 2)` to see the actual object structure you get. Maybe it is an array...

Comment: If you refer to the jsonplaceholder response, then see the snippet that I added to my answer. You can run and see the user id being output.

Answer (score 4):

`result.json()` will return a `Promise` that you need to `await`.

Currently, you are converting `Promise` object returned by `result.json()` into string and that is what gets logged on the console.

```
const result = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
const data = await result.json();
console.log('8. await: ' + data);
```

#### Edit:

> how to get the userId

You are getting `undefined` because you are converting object returned by `await result.json()` in to string and when any object is converted to string, you get something like `"[object Object]"`.

Just do not convert the object returned by `await result.json()` into string and simple access the `userId` property

```
console.log('8. await: ' + (await result.json()).userId);
```

See the following snippet

```js
async function fetchData() { 
  const result = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  const data = await result.json();
  console.log(String(data));        // what you are doing
  console.log(data);                // what you should do
}

fetchData();
```